# How to add a Script to a Instantiated gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I have to add a script to an Instantiated prefab, but the original prefab can't have the script attached, so I'm trying to add it with `gameObject.AddComponent` because at least in the inspector scripts are shown as components.

This is my line of code:

```cs
ObjectInstance.AddComponent(ScriptTest);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
The name "ScriptTest" does not exist in the current context.
```

Do I have to declarate it at the start with: `public Script ScriptTest`?

Comment: Can you show the content of `ScriptTest` .. this is c# and in particular Unity with `MonoBehaviour` components .. anything you want to attach to an object should be written as `public class ScriptTest : MonoBehaviour { ... }` and be in a file with exactly the same name (`ScriptTest.cs` where the `.cs` is not displayed within Unity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should do it like this.

```
ObjectInstance.AddComponent<ScriptTest>();
```

Second of all, make sure ScriptTest have the same namespace as your current script. If ScriptTest have a different namespace then you should add the namespace at the top of your script, somthing like this:

```
using ScriptTestNamespace;
```